# Is it possible to rotate the direction of MDBOXLAYOUT in kivymd?

Tags: rotation, kivymd

I want to create an interface that I'll split into two different parts with MDBOXLAYOUT. But I want also to invert one of that parts in order to authorize the using by two persons at the same time.

I tried to use the property orientation and I set the value to 180 degree but it's doesn't work. So now I want to invert one of the screen so the widget will be displayed as mirror.

This is my python code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp

#from kivy.lang import Builder 

from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen 

from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout 

from random import *

class Interface(MDBoxLayout):

    pass

class MyMath_GameApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):

        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"

MyMath_GameApp().run()
```

This is my kv code:

```
Interface:

<Interface>:

    orientation:"vertical"

    MDBoxLayout:

        rotation:180

        md_bg_color:1,1,0,1

        MDLabel:

            text:"hello"

            

    MDBoxLayout:

        md_bg_color:1,0,0,1

        MDLabel:

            text:"hello3"
```